# Mountable deduplicating container

Tags: mount, encryption, container, deduplication

I want a container that I can mount which dedups files within it.

Basically, I'd like to have a simple backup solution where I mount it, copy my home folder with the name "Home (Feb 9)" and it only increase in size with the new files.

Using regular compression is unfortunately no where near as fast/compressed as simple deduping since I'll have multiple copies of the same files.

If there is also encryption supported with the container, that would be amazing.

Comment: You can use any encryption solution e.g. [dm-crypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dm-crypt) and any backup solution that takes care of efficiently storing a history of files e.g. [rsnapshot](http://rsnapshot.org/) which uses hard links for file-based deduplication.

Answer (score 1):

Thinking outside the box now: use `git`. Every backup can be a new commit, which can take an arbitrary description message, and records the exact timestamps and file permissions anyway. `git` will implicitly deduplicate, as it works with file hashes and will only store the ones that change (all the "objects" are stored internally and accessed through hashes, so a rename is also detected). It doesn't matter that much, if the files aren't text-based, it works for binary just as well, just merging doesn't (but you don't need that for backup anyway).

Additionally, with `git` you also have all the machinery to checkout any past version, merge or branch them, purge old branches, and restoration from backup is also trivial. For purposes of backup, the original folder doesn't have to be a git repository - you can still copy things to the repository and commit changes. A proper `.gitignore` file will also automatically ignore specified files so you only save essentials.

Comment: git must use compression, right? is it configurable to use xz or gz or others?

Comment: It compresses with zlib. The process is somewhat "lazy", because it's meant to be incremental (commits adding a few lines to code or something) - it would be ridiculous to unpack, deduplicate and compress each time - it does it as it pleases. You can trigger storage optimization with `git gc`. For text files, it's better than any generic tools. For binaries, I'd have to research to see how it handles differential compression, but those frequently have their own native compression and can't be compressed much more than a few percent (movies, pdfs, images).